# Gmail visiting link destinations when clicking links in emails - Anyone else seen this?

Tags: gmail

I've got an app that sends emails with links to allow end users to triage leads (mark them dead, sold, disqualified, etc.)  The links go a landing page on the server where the end user submits a POST form to register the update.

Looking at the server side logs, when the end user clicks the link in gmail (web client or an app), I can see the request from their browser to the server.  Frequently, I'll see additional GET requests from google (specifically cache.google.com) following the end users click.  These are probably ok, just google doing some form of spam/malicious link checking.

Under some undefined circumstances, after the google GETs, there is occasionally a POST.  This seems plan wrong or anti-social at least.  It is problematic for me because it causes an errant status update to be registered or submits a form that needs the end user to enter information.

Here's a log snippet showing an instance:

```
{ my IP redacted } test.com - [03/May/2022:16:51:27 -0400] "GET /app/?m=l&t=3Nj6QOWbhvmde35zPqBsuyl71YMTlEur&s=19 HTTP/1.1" 200 7543 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.4 Safari/605.1.15"
167.142.232.4 test.com - [03/May/2022:17:23:17 -0400] "GET /app/?m=l&t=3Nj6QOWbhvmde35zPqBsuyl71YMTlEur&s=19 HTTP/1.1" 200 7543 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.84 Safari/537.36"
167.142.232.4 test.com - [03/May/2022:17:23:18 -0400] "GET /app/js/Common/emailValidation.js HTTP/1.1" 200 413 "https://test.com/app/?m=l&t=3Nj6QOWbhvmde35zPqBsuyl71YMTlEur&s=19" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.84 Safari/537.36"
167.142.232.4 test.com - [03/May/2022:17:23:18 -0400] "GET /app/js/Leads/landing.js?4 HTTP/1.1" 200 7214 "https://test.com/app/?m=l&t=3Nj6QOWbhvmde35zPqBsuyl71YMTlEur&s=19" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.84 Safari/537.36"
167.142.232.4 test.com - [03/May/2022:17:23:18 -0400] "GET /app/js/Leads/leadDetailValidators.js HTTP/1.1" 200 2812 "https://test.com/app/?m=l&t=3Nj6QOWbhvmde35zPqBsuyl71YMTlEur&s=19" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.84 Safari/537.36"
167.142.232.4 test.com - [03/May/2022:17:23:19 -0400] "GET /app/images/email/logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 4796 "https://test.com/app/?m=l&t=3Nj6QOWbhvmde35zPqBsuyl71YMTlEur&s=19" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.84 Safari/537.36"
167.142.232.4 test.com - [03/May/2022:17:23:20 -0400] "POST /app/index.cgi HTTP/1.1" 302 - "https://test.com/app/?m=l&t=3Nj6QOWbhvmde35zPqBsuyl71YMTlEur&s=19" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.84 Safari/537.36"
167.142.232.4 test.com - [03/May/2022:17:23:21 -0400] "GET /app/index.cgi?m=l&t=3Nj6QOWbhvmde35zPqBsuyl71YMTlEur HTTP/1.1" 200 4828 "https://test.com/app/?m=l&t=3Nj6QOWbhvmde35zPqBsuyl71YMTlEur&s=19" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.84 Safari/537.36"
```

Details:

- Line 1 - end user clicks
- Lines 2-6 - google loading the landing page and resources.
- Line 7 - google posting to the form on landing page
- Line 8 - redirect to form submission results

Other Details Noted:

- The landing page has some javascript that changes some for the form data in the post. I can see that google is running the javascript on the page.
- I removed the javascript on the page and simplified the form to include only basic form (no css, no js, bare minimum marker, no submit button in form) and the form still gets POSTed by google.

Questions:

- Has anyone else seen this behavior?
- What triggers this behavior?  (we have other applications that do similar operations with links and don't see extra GETs or POSTs when clicking through from gmail)
- What are some other ways to debug the situation?

Answer (score 1):

It can be due to the preview functionality of the gmail application. If your users are long-clicking the link in the email, a preview window will pop which navigates to the url (at least on ios) I assume this preview window doesn't navigates directly to the url but rather through a reverse proxy that google provides, then things gets complicated after this point when your users try to submit a form inside this preview window.

I'm not sure of it but you can easily try/test the case to see if this is the problem or not.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I've seen the problem in gmail on safari desktop, chrome on linux and in the iOS gmail app. I have not specifically triggered the link preview myself yet.  I'm not sure the timing makes sense though for previews, the follow up requests from cache.google.com show up minutes to hours after the end user clicks.  Regardless, the GET part is fine, POSTing automatically to the form on the landing page is bad or unexpected at least.

Comment: A quick question, is the form method POST explicitly defined inline like method="post" and the submit button is a regular button without any javascript?

Comment: yes, form has explicit `method="post"`.  The form tag doesn't have an action attribute normally, but I added one for testing and it got submitted either way.  re: submit button, there is button `type="submit"` with a javascript handler on the form's submit event; under normal circumstances, it prevents the form from being submitted without required fields.  it doesn't stop the bot from submitting though.  I also tried removing the submit button entirely and the bot still submits the form.

Comment: If not the preview thing, would you mind trying to place a robots.txt by denying/disallowing the url from googlebot? I wasn't expecting googlebot to post, but it seems it even can randomly fill an input and post the form.

Comment: I haven't tried the `robots.txt` stuff yet (need to move some stuff around for that to work), but I did try the supposedly equivalent meta `name="robots"` equivalent on the landing page to no avail.  Will try to see if an OG robots.txt does the trick.

I'm guessing that there's a loop hole about crawling to check for malicious content is different that crawling to index so the bot doesn't follow robots.txt guidance.

Comment: @JasonCrowther: Any luck with finding a solution to this problem? I see similar behaviour in another app and am looking for a solution.

Comment: @Albert-Jan Verhees: regrettably, no, I was not able to find a way to stop the problem. I ended up adding a captcha in the form on the landing page to stop the errant submissions, sigh.